# How to use if and else condition when matching xpath count =0 and greater than 0

Tags: xpath, robotframework

```
${result}=    Run keyword and ignore error    Get Matching Xpath Count xpath=${node A}

Run keyword if    '${result[0]}' == '0'   
click element    ${node A}

ELSE

click element    ${node B}
```

how say for else condition here

Comment: This seems like an almost exact duplicate of your first question. Can you explain how this question is different?

Answer (score 0):

```
${result}=    Run keyword and ignore error    Get Matching Xpath Count xpath=${node A}
Run keyword if    '${result[0]}' == '0'
...    click element    ${node A}
...    ELSE
...    click element    ${node B}
```

Does the above work?  If not, please provide more information

Comment: as I asked, can you please provide more information?  It's very difficult to help if we don't even know what error you are encountering?